# How to monitor a network port that is being used for a ftp service?

Tags: java, ftp

Every time a ftp connection is established I want a java program to get triggered.

I am not sure how to check the FTP connections. Is there a way to monitor the port so that I can acknowledge when FTP gets the new connection?

I've researched a bit and found the FTPClient class which basically suggests I need to do my own ftpclient, but I want to know if there is another way.

Even an external program could be an option.

Comment: Do you want the Java program to run on the client side or on the server side?  What will it do?  (Depending on what it will do, there may be other options)

Comment: it would be running on the server side, basically the program will be reading the files that the client put on it.

Comment: What is your FTP server?

Comment: I'm not sure which one I will use, maybe a filezilla,  I'm still planing, if you know one that helps to do what I want I really appreciate suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of approaches:

- Have the FTP service itself launch the java app (sounds expensive) or notify a running Java app / service.  This will be the simplest approach ...
- Use some kind of external monitoring; e.g.

  - A generic packet packet sniffing tool (like `wireshark` or `tcpdump`) might be able to trigger an external application.  If not, you may be able to get it to log info to a file that you scan for connection events.
  - You could possible implement something using jpcap to do your own packet sniffing in Java
  - There is a Linux utility called `tcpspy` that logs TCP/IP connection details to syslog.  You could configure it log to a specific file and monitor that file, alternatively, you could modify `tcpspy` to launch or notify a Java app directly.

Comment: notify a running Java service is exactly what I intended to do but I'm having troubles with the part of notify my service when the FTP service get a new connection.
the packet sniffing option seems good I'll research about it

Answer (score 0):

> it would be running on the server side, basically the program will be reading the files that the client put on it.

Consider using a file watcher.  It doesn't seem that you really care that the file gets there using FTP (in fact, in the future it might get there by some other means), but just that the file is present and needs to be processed.

See [Watching a Directory for Changes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) for details on how to write one.

Comment: Actually is important the files get there by FTP because it will be the only way, the files come from a mainframe and the only method allowed to transmit files is FTP (company rules). the File Watcher is an option but it does not achieve the issue as I want.

Answer (score 0):

I have a program that does a similar task server-side with java. It checks if files exist in a folder and launches the rest of the code if so. Like this:

```
public static boolean needToConvert(){
    //get list of companies
    List<String> companies = getCompanyNames();
    //check whether a file exists in folder of company
    for(String company: companies){
        if (new File(INPUT_LOCATION + company).list().length > 0){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is a rather in-expensive task, so you could just set the server to "check"; say, every minute or so.

Comment: good suggestion, I'm considering it, but I rather prefer to start reading the files just after the FTP service finishes to put the files.

Comment: It sounds like either way you do it, you're going to expend resources constantly listening in some way, whether it's checking the ftp connection, or looking for new files. I have mine checking every 3 seconds, and processing immediately after it catches a new file. It archives it after processing and the program begins checking again. Good luck either way!